# Is it possible to set read preference at the collection level?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a large collection of metadata, and I'd like to know if there's a way to set a `secondaryPreferred` read preference once, for the whole collection, rather than setting it repeatedly at the query level all over the application code.

Is this possible? Currently using mongoose 3.6.x.

Comment: You should be able to specify it in the connection string `readPreference=secondaryPreferred`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out myself - it can be set in the schema options.

Example:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  thing: String,
  count: Number
}, {read: 'secondaryPreferred'});
```